# Guess the output for two values that multiply by each other with machine learning (python)

Tags: python

I want to have two numbers that multiply by each other, then predict the output.

for example:

```
x = [1,2,5, 11,8]
y = [5,4,10, 5,1]
z = [5,8,50,55,8]

guess = myModel([10,4])
print(guess)
-> 40
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what is mymodel ?

Comment: myModel would be [x,y,z]. So I would want to put in [10,4] and get out 40 as a z value